# AngularJS ng-repeat - http.gs retrieving data, but not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and trying to integrate it within my application. I am attempting to use a simple `$http.get` to a .JSON file, which displaying the matching contents in a `ng-repeat`

Here my get:

```
$scope.countries = [];
$http.get('/resources/data/countries-report.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data.countries;
    // alert(JSON.stringify($scope.countries));
    console.log(data.countries);
    console.log(data.countries.population);
}).error(function(error) {
    alert('error');
});
```

Here's my .JSON file:

```
{
  "firstName"   : "Joe",
  "surName" : "Bloggs",
  "countries" : [
      { "name": "France", "population": "63.1" },
      { "name": "Span", "population": "52.3" },
      { "name": "United Kingdom", "population": "61.8" }
  ]
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries">
    {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}
</li>
```

When viewing in the browser, all that is displayed is:

- has population of
- has population of
- has population of

It seems as though my code can see there are 3 countries, as when i add or remove from my .JSON file, the list in the HTML modifies accordingly, however, the contents of the .JSON is not displaying.

Have i forgot to return the data from my `.get`??

**** UPDATE ***************************

As some have mentioned, my code seems to be correct, i think i know what the problem may be.

My application makes use of a HTML templating structure using Swig which accesses .JSON file using {{ }}.. Could this be causing confusion with Angular?

**** UPDATE ***************************

If i change:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

to

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
    }
);
```

And:

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries">
     {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}
</li>
```

To:

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries">
     {[{country.name}]} has population of {[{country.population}]}
</li>
```

Then the correct values are displayed.

Comment: Are you getting the data inside your controller?

Comment: @BKM - I can see the data is being logged in the console using: console.log(data.countries);... This is displayed: [Object { name="France", population="63.1"}, Object { name="United Kingdom", population="61.8"}, Object { name="Spain", population="16.7"}, Object { name="Greece", population="23.5"}]

Comment: Can you check and print your country object `{{country | json}}` inside ng-repeat.

Comment: Seems good to me: http://plnkr.co/edit/VXLIXGlcRQZwjNMi97sc?p=preview   I think you just have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @FizerKhan - placing {{countries | json}} in my HTML displays: ""

Comment: No, just put `{{ country | json }}` not countries.

Comment: @FizerKhan - that is also showing - ""

Comment: As you have found your solution, don't hesitate to add it as an answer and accept it. Maybe add an explanation of how two technologies are conflicting with each other and such.

Comment: Check that no directives which may alter the scope are present on the elements or their parents.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the data in the array of object form like

```
[
  { 
    id:1,
    ima:gh.jpg,
    data: 
    [
      {
        anotherid:1,
        my:w,
        ki:y
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id=2,
    ima:jh.jpg
  }
]
```